# terraform plan after terraform import fails with user not authorized

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

So, I have existing resources that I have to import. Terraform plan, tries to create many resources (which are already there)  and thus the need to import.

Terraform plan e.g outputs this when run from a CD pipeline:

```
 # module.databricks.databricks_catalog.catalog["dev"] will be created
  + resource "databricks_catalog" "catalog" {
      + force_destroy = false
      + id            = (known after apply)
      + metastore_id  = (known after apply)
      + name          = "dev"
      + owner         = (known after apply)
    }
```

then I run terraform import in an IDE by (using my account):

```
terraform import module.databricks.databricks_catalog.catalog[\"dev\"] dev
```

when I run terraform plan using my account in the IDE, I see that resource is skipped and one less shown by terraform plan to create.

But when I now run terraform plan through the CD pipeline, I get an error

```
##[error]Terraform command 'plan' failed with exit code '1'.
##[error]╷
│ Error: cannot read catalog: User not authorized
```

when I delete the state file and start afresh, the terraform plan from the pipeline works well.

What am I doing wrong?

this is the resource: [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/catalog)

Comment: Well, terraform calls different APIs for new resources than an update. So terraform must be calling an API you don't have permissions to. Run terraform in debug mode and look at the logs to see what API call is having the permission issue.

Comment: That makes sense. I saw that the pipeline spn didn’t have some permissions. I was tripped because it was able to do the plan when there was no state file. It thus makes sense that when there is something in the state file, terraform actually makes a call to the actual resource (databricks), which fails. In case of empty, it just assumes there is nothing to check and does not make a call to the resource and assumes everything will be a create. I will try inport again, now that I have added permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I also stuck on same issue and below is the solution how i resolved it.

I have resources that were initially deployed manually and later imported into Terraform. Specifically, you've imported a Databricks catalog into the Terraform state file. To read this catalog, the "use catalog" permission is required.

The challenge arises when running terraform plan because the service principal used in the Azure DevOps pipeline lacks the necessary "use catalog" permission, leading to errors. The Terraform state file retains access grant information for a specific user which i have used in my local IDE, causing authorization issues when running the CI/CD pipeline.

Deleting the state file eliminates the defined permissions, allowing terraform plan to execute without errors. However, when proceeding to terraform apply, permission issues resurface since access to the metastore is still lacking for catalog creation.

[Find the snap here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdMTJ.png)

To resolve this, you have to give the permission on service principal in databricks.